# Extract value from the map basis on which key is present

Tags: java, hashmap

I need to get `userId` value from the map and that can be present either in `user1` key or  `user2` key or `user3` key or `user4` key in the map. Only one key will be present in the map at a time, no multiple keys will be present.

So I started off with below code which checks if `user1` is present or not and if it is present extract `user1` key value otherwise extract `user2` key value. So should I keep adding `user3` and `user4` check as well in it? If yes it will become very long..

```
Map<String, String> holder = Utils.parseStringToMap(payload);
String userId = holder.containsKey("user1") ? holder.get("user1") : holder.get("user2");
```

Is there any better way by which I can extract `userId` value  depending on what key is present? I am using Java 7.

**Note:** here key name in the map for that field can be any name. It won't be `userx` where x is a number so I cannot use for loop logic here.

Comment: if key can be *any* name, maybe you'll just take first value from map? ;)

Comment: that map has lot of other things as well apart from that key I am looking for.

Comment: that means you know what you are looking for and key belongs to some set of possible values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the keys in a loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    final String key = "user" + i;
    if (holder.containsKey(key)) {
        // ... process the found key and value
        break;
    }
}
```

This would allow you to easily extend your keyspace in the future by just changing the upper bound (`4` in this example).

If your names do not have a common pattern like `userX`, you could have an explicit list of them:

```
String[] keys = {"key1", "user2", "somethingelse"};
for (final String key : keys) {
    if (holder.containsKey(key)) {
        // ... process the found key and value
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Those names I just came up with `userx`. it can be any name in general.  let me clarify the question.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should introduce a helper method that provides a var-args parameter to transmit any userId `String` to match.
It would be more readable and flexible.
For example :

```
public String getUserId(Map<String, String> valueByUserIds, String... userIdsToMatch){
   for (String userIdToMatch : userIdsToMatch){
       if (holder.containsKey(userIdToMatch)){
         // or spare an invocation by using only holder.get(userIdToMatch) if the value should never be null
          return holder.get(userIdToMatch);
       }
   }
   return null; // or throw an exception
}
```

And you can use it in this way :

```
Map<String, String> holder = Utils.parseStringToMap(payload);
String userValue = getUserId(holder, "user1");
String userValue = getUserId(holder, "user1", "user2");
String userValue = getUserId(holder, "user1", "user2", "user3");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd wrap the possible keys in a list and iterate over them:

```
private static String getFromFirstKey
    (Map<String, String> map, List<String> keys) {
    for (String key : keys) {
        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            return map.get(key);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> holder = Utils.parseStringToMap(payload);
    String userId =
      getFromFirstKey(holder, Arrays.asList("user1", "user2", "user3", "user4"));
}
```